# Laravel migration default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I didn't understand what is the effect of the `default` option in the migrations.

I can see that the column in the database is defined with default value, but the models are ignore it completely. Say I have a `Book` model that reflect the `books` table in the database. I have migration to create the books table:

```
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
          ->string('author');
          ->string('title');
          ->decimal('price', 4, 1)->default(100);
          ->timestamps();
});
```

When I create a new instance of `Book` model I see:

```
$book = new Book();
var_dump($book->price); //Always 0...
```

The default value is ignored and the attribute is not sets correctly.
Ok, I can get it, because it is a new object and it shouldn't get the default values from the DB. **But** if I tries to save model like:

```
$book = new Book();
$book->author = 'Test'
$book->title = 'Test'
$book->save();
```

It is saves **0** in the field `price` in the database!

So what is the point of the `default` option in the migrations?

By the way...
It wasn't be better if the model see inside the migration (if exists) what are the fields types and behavior instead to define it manually in the model and the migration? And moreover, even to create a validator automatically for the model. I think that it was possible with small change of the migration structure, so why it is not like that?

Comment: In Laravel documentation there it says "Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries needed to make the specified adjustments to the column." Do you have that dependency?

Comment: I am not modifying any columns, why should I have this?

Comment: Because `default($value)` is a modifier in migrations and this is prerequisite for modifiers.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Put the default value in single quote and it will work as intended. An example of migration:

```
$table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');
            $table->timestamps();
```

**EDIT :** in your case ->default('100.0');

Comment: It didn't works. After adding single quotes and run `php artisan migrate:refresh` it still ignores the default value

Comment: I tested it before posting the answer, are you sure it doesn't works ? I will remove this answer then

Comment: give it a try with integer value ? I know you want default float but just give it a try

Comment: Now with your `$table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');` it works. maybe it is happens because the `Form::model` that I am using for saving models. In that case I must to define the default values in the model manually?

Comment: I am not very sure but looks like so

Comment: I came here because i wanted to know how to add the default value on the migrate file itself, using the artisan command.  e.g. `php artisan make:migration add_action_to_task_table --table=tasks --default="someString"`  I would like to add a string using the cli command.  Any suggestions here?  I cant find the right documentation on this.

Comment: It worked for me. But does someone know if this is intended behaviour? Seems strange.

Comment: It seems to not work in the case of decimal and text

Answer (score 8):

Might be a little too late to the party, but hope this helps someone with similar issue.

The reason why your default value doesnt't work is because the migration file sets up the default value in your database (MySQL or PostgreSQL or whatever), and not in your Laravel application.

Let me illustrate with an example.

This line means Laravel is generating a new Book instance, as specified in your model. The new `Book` object will have properties according to the table associated with the model. Up until this point, nothing is written on the database.

```
$book = new Book();
```

Now the following lines are setting up the values of each property of the `Book` object. Same still, nothing is written on the database yet.

```
$book->author = 'Test'
$book->title = 'Test'
```

This line is the one writing to the database. After passing on the object to the database, then the empty fields will be filled by the database (may be default value, may be null, or whatever you specify on your migration file).

```
$book->save();
```

And thus, the default value will not pop up before you save it to the database.

But, that is not enough. If you try to access `$book->price`, it will still be null (or 0, i'm not sure). Saving it is only adding the defaults to the record in the database, and it won't affect the Object you are carrying around.

So, to get the instance with filled-in default values, you have to re-fetch the instance. You may use the

```
Book::find($book->id);
```

Or, a more sophisticated way by refreshing the instance

```
$book->refresh();
```

And then, the next time you try to access the object, it will be filled with the default values.

Answer (score 5):

You can simple put the default value using default(). See the example

```
 $table->enum('is_approved', array('0','1'))->default('0');
```

I have used enum here and the default value is 0.

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 6 you have to add 'change' to your migrations file as follows:

```
$table->enum('is_approved', array('0','1'))->default('0')->change();
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem you face is not about the migration file. The value turns into 0 every time because you didn't change $fillable on your model. When you forget to add recently added column to $fillable of its model, Laravel inserts 0.