# Setting default value for Laravel Migration

Tags: laravel, database-migration, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel 5.6 and has a multi-auth funcitonality and it works fine. I have user and admin tables in my DB. How can i set a default value on admin table like NAME, EMAIL and PASSWORD? So everytime i run `php artisan migrate:refresh` i will have the default NAME EMAIL and PASSWORD in admin table? Thank you!

Comment: You can use `->default(val)` in a migration to assign a default value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel migration default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662955/laravel-migration-default-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a little clarification there are two possible answers to your question. If you are asking about columns in your database tabled having default values this has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662955/laravel-migration-default-value/) but it is simply by chaining the method `default` on your attribute.

```
$table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');
```

If you are asking about populating a row in your database whenever you migrate refresh. You can use [seeders](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding):

> Laravel includes a simple method of seeding your database with test
>   data using seed classes. All seed classes are stored in the
>   `database/seeds` directory. Seed classes may have any name you wish, but
>   probably should follow some sensible convention, such as
>   `UsersTableSeeder`, etc. By default, a `DatabaseSeeder` class is defined
>   for you. From this class, you may use the `call` method to run other
>   seed classes, allowing you to control the seeding order.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'default_name',
            'email' => 'default@mail.com',
            'password' => 'password',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And afterwards just call:

`php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`