# Laravel Default Value for Decimal Column Type

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to set a default value for a decimal column. But I still received a "Not null violation error".

What I have tried:

1. default('0')
2. default(0)
3. default('0.00') ([solution from another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662955/laravel-migration-default-value))
4. default('00000000000000000.00')
5. default(0.00)

None of what I've tried works. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Migration file]

[image: Not null violation error]

Comment: have you tried default(0.00), pass other non-zero double like 0.12 in order to validate format or disabling SQL strict mode?

Comment: @moonvader still not null violation

Comment: the migration is probably working, but you are passing the null value in the query when you insert new records

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$table->decimal('exit_fee', 19, 2)->default('00000000000000000.00');
```

and run migrate will see

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8NQF.png

Comment: still not null violation

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in a different question wich kind of resembles your question.

```
$table->decimal('exit_fee', 19, 2)->default('00000000000000000');
```